# Jest - spyOn does not code cover actual implementation

Tags: typescript, jestjs, code-coverage

I working on Jest Unit testing for Typescript, I created a method

```
addNumbers:() {
     return 6;
}
```

it is just a static test method for testing purpose.

I created a Unit Test using jest

```
spyOn(object, 'addNumbers').mockReturnValue(6);
expect(object.addNumbers).toHaveBeenCalled(); // expect is success
```

The Unit test is working fine, but while checking the Code Coverage "return 6;" is not covered.

Not sure what is missing , configuration or any other issues.

Because once this is working , need to implement in actual Code.

If any other information is required, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

spyOn(object, 'addNumbers').mockReturnValue(6);

Here you have mocked the function that is why your original function is not called.

Just use like this, Do not mock only spyOn

```
const addNumbersSpy = spyOn(object, 'addNumbers')
expect(addNumbersSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: Hello @user1263961 can you check the answer and make it correct if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Dinindu, I tried the above steps and Unit test is passing, my actual issue is , When checking  the Code Coverage, the Lines in method are not Covered.

Comment: Hi @user1263961 In your test you have to call addNumbers function otherwise it will not cover

Comment: Please add the full test here

Comment: Main.ts
`code`


export class Main {
    addNumber(a: number, b: number) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
export default Main;

Main.spec.ts
`code`
import { Main } from './main'
describe('Add Number', () => {
    test('sum', () => {
        let a = new Main();
        let b = jest.spyOn(a, 'addNumber').mockReturnValue(3).mockImplementation(() => 3);
        expect(a.addNumber(1, 2)).toEqual(3)
    })
})

Answer (score 0):

This is a dead question, but I figured it couldn't hurt to write an explanation in case anybody stumbles across this later (as I did).

I believe what you are observing is expected behavior - if you are mocking a function in a test, then the function that is being mocked is not actually ever being called. I would not want code that is not being executed in the test to be covered in the code coverage report.

It sounds like you were confused on how to actually test your method; a unit test for the `addNumber` method from `Main` class would look something like this:

```
import { Main } from './main'
describe('Add Number', () => {
  test('sum', () => {
    // Arrange
    let main = new Main();
    // Act
    let result = a.addNumber(1, 2);
    // Assert
    expect(result).toEqual(3)
  })
})
```

Mocks are a utility to help you test code - mocks themselves are not meant to be tested.

Comment: This no different form the given answer